# What's IE6/7 safe way to pass json_encoded data from PHP into jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have several situations where I need to pass multi-dimensional PHP arrays into Javascript/jQuery. The PHP function `json_encode()` seems to do this rather well. I've seen some examples that use `$.parseJSON`, but I'm not sure if this is for IE6 compatibility or some other issue. Can anyone elaborate if this is the correct format to use in JavaScript. Assume this is javascript/jQuery as part of a PHP view.

```
var sections = <?php echo json_encode($sections); ?>;
```

Or, perhaps this would be better?

```
var sections = <?php if (!empty($sections)) { echo json_encode($sections); } else { echo "new Array()"; } ?>;
```

Or, do I need $.parseJSON? It seems to throw an error.

```
var sections = $.parseJSON(<?php echo json_encode($sections); ?>);
```

Does anyone know of any IE6 issues I should be aware of? If I should use `parseJSON()`, is it used with single or double quotes?

Thanks in advance,
Jeff Walters

Comment: For the parseJSON-type you have to wrap it into a string literal.

Comment: If sections is just empty, either `[]` or `{}` would suffice OTOH (in the blessed circumstance of no longer having MSIE6), which is what PHP would generate usually...

Comment: Your first piece of code should have been enough since json can be directly converted to a javascript object in that way. IE6/7 shouldn't have issues.

Comment: `.parseJSON` is used as security precaution on foreign data. An object literal is sufficient, if you are supplying it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about IE, but as long as you aren't dealing with JSON *strings* in JavaScript you will not need any `parseJSON` function. Just putting them out into the script text should be fine.